# Hard-coding URLs vs Nested Set vs Combo in Content System

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, url-routing, content-management-system

I've been putting together a database to handle content produced for a site, however, thinking about the long-term, I'm unsure if I have the best system.

At present I'm using the routing method of passing everything via `index.php` which `.htaccess` routes as follows `index.php?route=example/url` (user sees `http://www.domain.com/example/url`)

At present the database is setup like below:

```
uid            | title        | content | category
--------------------------------------------------
/              | Home         | aaa     | 1
/example       | Example      | bbb     | 2
/example/url   | Example: URL | ccc     | 2
```

Though I am not sure if this is the best approach, especially if I wanted to rename `example` to `something` - I'd have to rename each URL...

So I've also thought about the Nested Set method (such as http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2547-PHP-Manipulate-database-records-in-hierarchical-trees.html) though this would just show lots of different numbers in the database where I could access everything by it's node. Example below;

```
node | left | right | name
--------------------------
1    | 1    | 6     | Home
2    | 2    | 5     | Example
3    | 3    | 4     | URL
```

Then I could use the node as the uid? But I'm unsure how I could translate `http://www.domain.com/example/url` to the `uid` equalling 3...

I already do have a category column in my database at the moment, to categorise the content, though I could potentially alter this.

I'm basically looking for suggestions about how to proceed, because as the site gets more content it will be harder to change the setup - so I want to ideally get this right from day one.

- Which of the two is better for scalability?
- If the second, how to translate the URL to the node?
- Could I somehow combine both so that the original database stores the uid as the node number, then do a join of some sort to make the uid be a url (as in 1) - then ]

  ^ I think I'd prefer this (the third), but unsure how to do in MySQL exactly, with some other benefits:

  - I could replace my category system with the parent node - which may be better
  - I could also then in theory store the node ID within a stats system, rather than a URL

If anyone can give some help/suggestions - I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested set model probably is a good choice here. That'd result in a table layout like (`id,left,right` are the fields required by the nested set model, the others contain the respective content):

```
| id | left | right | uid | title | content | category |
```

More details on how to perform a particular query can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100105135622/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html).

However I would not perform the look up on the database but a simple array cache:

```
new array('/' => array('content' => 'aaa', 'category' => 'bbbb'),
          '/example/' => array(),
          .....
);
```

This cache can be build up very easy (though expensive) and queried very easy.

On a side note: i suspect you're trying to model page content here. Maybe you should refactor you database structure then as this table would have two responsibilities (url->content mapping and content).

Comment: yes - I would keep the mapping away from the content if using the 2nd method ... an array cache sounds interesting, though as you say expensive (I imagine in terms of eventual size)

Comment: even having `id, left, right, name, uid` in the mapping table would be good, though I'd want to keep the `uid` up to date where possible ... then in the content table have the `id` (the node/id of the leaf)?

Comment: That'd be `id, left, right, name, content` for the mapping (if you want the links to have other names than the content itself, else remove the name here!). `content` is a reference to the content id on an other table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `index.php?route=example/url`, you could always do something like this:

```
$args = explode( '/', $_GET['route'] );
$args = filter_var_array( $_GET['route'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

Then your values of $args would be:

```
0 -> example
1 -> url
```

etc. You could then use these values to determine what template to load, and what content to grab from the database, or whatever else you're doing already.

HTH.

Comment: In a way, doesn't seem all that different from how I'm currently doing it - though the way I'm doing it at the moment would be faster as I just need to simply find example/url within the uid column